# Analyze backtrace of Kernel panic on Android / find cause

Tags: android, linux-kernel, crash, crash-dumps, panic

I have [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88198/bootloops-random-restarts-on-note-2-lte-worse-with-sim-inserted-analyze-kern) problem on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 LTE with random reboots and kind of clean restarts in the kernel logs (no oops / panic, even though some usb errors) and now I got a kernel panic in the last_kmsg log. In this log I recognized 10 attempts to start the modem, which all failed and after that the kernel had a panic because the restarts timed out.

The 5.5 sec interval repeating modem start sequence:

```
    [11041.906148] c3 SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses transition SIDs
    [11041.906198] c3 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file 'devices'
    [11041.906237] c3 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '001'
    [11041.906584] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    [11041.906626] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: ohci_s5p_init, ohci:e78bd108
    [11041.906702] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: created debug files
    [11041.906739] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: irq 134, io mem 0x12590000
    [11041.906765] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: ohci_s5p_start, ohci:e78bd108
    [11041.964043] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: OHCI controller state
    [11041.964071] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: OHCI 1.0, NO legacy support registers
    [11041.964103] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: control 0x083 HCFS=operational CBSR=3
    [11041.964134] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: cmdstatus 0x00000 SOC=0
    [11041.964162] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: intrstatus 0x00000004 SF
    [11041.964189] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: intrenable 0x8000005a MIE RHSC UE RD WDH
    [11041.964221] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: hcca frame #0005
    [11041.964246] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.a 02000203 POTPGT=2 NPS NDP=3(3)
    [11041.964278] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.b 00000000 PPCM=0000 DR=0000
    [11041.964308] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.status 00008000 DRWE
    [11041.964336] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [0] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11041.964367] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [1] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11041.964398] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [2] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11041.964455] c3 usb usb1: default language 0x0409
    [11041.964488] c3 usb usb1: udev 1, busnum 1, minor = 0
    [11041.964512] c3 usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [11041.964544] c3 usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [11041.964576] c3 usb usb1: Product: s5p OHCI
    [11041.964596] c3 usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.0.31-1665483 ohci_hcd
    [11041.964624] c3 usb usb1: SerialNumber: s5p-ohci
    [11041.964647] c3 call_battery_notify : VID : 0x1d6b, PID : 0x1 skipped.
    [11041.966018] c3 usb usb1: usb_probe_device
    [11041.966043] c3 usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
    [11041.966091] c3 usb usb1: adding 1-0:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
    [11041.966433] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: usb_probe_interface
    [11041.966458] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
    [11041.966486] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
    [11041.966519] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
    [11041.966540] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: standalone hub
    [11041.966561] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: no power switching (usb 1.0)
    [11041.966588] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: global over-current protection
    [11041.966613] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: power on to power good time: 4ms
    [11041.966646] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: local power source is good
    [11041.966670] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: no over-current condition exists
    [11041.966698] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: trying to enable port power on non-switchable hub
    [11041.967086] c3 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '001'
    [11042.065063] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: state 7 ports 3 chg 0000 evt 0000
    [11042.507953] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11042.507989] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]Mali: Mali frequency 350
    [11042.600676] c0 max77686: id=27, org=32, val=39Mali: Mali frequency 266
    [11042.615503] c0 Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 975000, 975000 
    [11042.616167] c0 max77686: id=29, org=22, val=1e
    [11042.616276] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11042.617801] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1e
    [11042.630343] c0 ssp_sensorhub_list: 1, 1, 7, 0
    [11042.630436] c3 ssp_sensorhub_read: 1, 1, 7, 0
    [11042.700695] c0 max77686: id=27, org=39, val=32
    [11042.715058] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!
    [11042.807917] c0 ssp_sensorhub_list: 1, 1, 7, -1
    [11042.807999] c3 ssp_sensorhub_read: 1, 1, 7, -1
    [11043.000039] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: auto-stop root hub
    [11043.115361] c0 Mali: Mali frequency 160
    [11043.115385] c0 Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 950000, 950000 
    [11043.115994] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1e, val=1c
    [11043.117567] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1c
    [11043.214166] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11043.214203] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11043.410042] c3 [TSP] change_dvfs_lockMali: = regulator_set_voltage: 975000, 975000 
    [11043.415651] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1c, val=1e
    [11043.417257] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1e
    [11043.417609] c0 Mali: Mali frequency 266
    [11043.487794] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11043.531224] c0 ssp_sensorhub_list: 1, 1, 7, 0
    [11043.531306] c3 ssp_sensorhub_read: 1, 1, 7, 0
    [11043.585046] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!Mali: Mali frequency 160
    [11043.915385] c0 Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 950000, 950000 
    [11043.915996] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1e, val=1c
    [11043.917558] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1c
    [11043.955037] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11043.955078] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11043.989765] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11044.050699] c0 max77686: id=27, org=32, val=39
    [11044.065060] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: hub_suspend
    [11044.065093] c3 usb usb1: bus auto-suspend
    [11044.065116] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: suspend root hub
    [11044.085068] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!
    [11044.200723] c0 max77686: id=27, org=39, val=32Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 975000, 975000 
    [11044.215657] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1c, val=1e
    [11044.217220] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1e
    [11044.217566] c0 Mali: Mali frequency 266
    [11044.349513] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11044.349561] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11044.408454] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11044.505054] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!
    [11044.970054] c0 ssp_sensorhub_list: 1, 1, 7, -1
    [11044.970135] c3 ssp_sensorhub_read: 1, 1, 7, -1
    [11045.163119] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11045.163158] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11045.209960] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]Mali: Mali frequency 160
    [11045.290403] c0 Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 950000, 950000 
    [11045.291016] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1e, val=1c
    [11045.292608] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1c
    [11045.300662] c0 max77686: id=27, org=32, val=39
    [11045.305045] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!
    [11045.400714] c0 max77686: id=27, org=39, val=32
    [11045.772455] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11045.772496] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11045.850770] c0 max77686: id=27, org=32, val=39
    [11045.879558] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11045.950749] c0 max77686: id=27, org=39, val=32
    [11045.975049] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 975000, 975000 
    [11046.100654] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1c, val=1e
    [11046.102222] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1e
    [11046.102574] c0 Mali: Mali frequency 266
    [11046.418723] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11046.418761] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11046.591588] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]Mali: Mali frequency 160
    [11046.600385] c3 Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 950000, 950000 
    [11046.600990] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1e, val=1c
    [11046.602552] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1c
    [11046.690049] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 975000, 975000 
    [11046.700650] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1c, val=1e
    [11046.702213] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1e
    [11046.702560] c0 Mali: Mali frequency 266
    [11047.017412] c0 ssp_sensorhub_list: 1, 1, 7, 0
    [11047.017545] c3 ssp_sensorhub_read: 1, 1, 7, 0
    [11047.094593] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11047.094632] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11047.171336] c3 mdm_modem_ioctl: Powering on mdm
    [11047.171361] c3 request_boot_lock_set
    [11047.171383] c3 mdm_do_soft_power_on: soft resetting mdm modem
    [11047.171409] c3 mdm_peripheral_disconnect
    [11047.171497] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: remove, state 4
    [11047.171532] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub graceful disconnect
    [11047.171572] c3 usb usb1: USB disconnect, device number 1 by usb_remove_hcd+0xac/0x160
    [11047.171607] c3 call_battery_notify : VID : 0x1d6b, PID : 0x1 skipped.
    [11047.171636] c3 usb usb1: unregistering device
    [11047.171658] c3 usb usb1: unregistering interface 1-0:1.0
    [11047.172032] c3 usb usb1: usb_disable_device nuking all URBs
    [11047.186272] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: OHCI controller state
    [11047.186303] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: OHCI 1.0, NO legacy support registers
    [11047.186339] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: control 0x4c3 RWE HCFS=suspend CBSR=3
    [11047.186372] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: cmdstatus 0x00000 SOC=0
    [11047.186399] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: intrstatus 0x00000004 SF
    [11047.186426] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: intrenable 0x0000005a RHSC UE RD WDH
    [11047.186460] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: hcca frame #0411
    [11047.186486] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.a 02000203 POTPGT=2 NPS NDP=3(3)
    [11047.186517] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.b 00000000 PPCM=0000 DR=0000
    [11047.186547] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.status 00008000 DRWE
    [11047.186576] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [0] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11047.186607] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [1] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11047.186637] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [2] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11047.186715] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: USB bus 1 deregistered
    [11047.205665] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: still being used(18)
    [11047.220402] c3 Mali: Mali frequency 160
    [11047.220427] c3 Mali: = regulator_set_voltage: 950000, 950000 
    [11047.221033] c0 max77686: id=29, org=1e, val=1c
    [11047.222593] c0 max77686_get_voltage: id=29, val=1c
    [11047.240041] c3 mdm_peripheral_connect
    [11047.240504] c3 set hsic lpa phy init
    [11047.240556] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: usb phy usage(18)
    [11047.240580] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: Already power on PHY
    [11047.240606] c3 usb: set_exynos_usb_phy_tune old phy1 tune=0x2831b3 t=1
    [11047.240646] c3 usb: set_exynos_usb_phy_tune new phy1 tune=0x2831b3
    [11047.240677] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: s5p_ehci_phy_init : 0x3c00000
    [11047.240708] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: reset hcs_params 0x1313 dbg=0 cc=1 pcc=3 ordered ports=3
    [11047.240747] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: reset hcc_params 2a016 thresh 1 uframes 256/512/1024 park LPM
    [11047.240805] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: S5P EHCI Host Controller
    [11047.240892] c3 SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses transition SIDs
    [11047.240962] c3 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file 'devices'
    [11047.241003] c3 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '001'
    [11047.241497] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    [11047.241616] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: park 0
    [11047.241657] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: support lpm
    [11047.241698] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: irq 134, io mem 0x12580000
    [11047.241733] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: reset command 0010006 (park)=0 ithresh=1 period=512 Reset HALT
    [11047.290052] c3 [TSP] change_dvfs_lock
    [11047.300635] c0 max77686: id=27, org=32, val=39
    [11047.349497] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11047.445028] c3 [TSP] DVFS Off!
    [11047.552955] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: P(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11047.552991] c3 [TSP] DVFS On![8]
    [11047.572045] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: startup error -110
    [11047.572079] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: USB bus 1 deregistered
    [11047.588162] c3 melfas-ts 3-0048: R(M)(60) [ 0]
    [11047.595394] c3 s5p-ehci s5p-ehci: Failed to add USB HCD
    [11047.595439] c3 s5p-ehci: probe of s5p-ehci failed with error -110
    [11047.595839] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: usb phy usage(22)
    [11047.595863] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: Already power on PHY
    [11047.595887] c3 usb: set_exynos_usb_phy_tune old phy1 tune=0x2831b3 t=1
    [11047.595926] c3 usb: set_exynos_usb_phy_tune new phy1 tune=0x2831b3
    [11047.595954] c3 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: s5p OHCI
    [11047.596022] c3 SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses transition SIDs
```

The Kernel panic and the last attempt:

```
    [11093.441028] c2 SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses transition SIDs
    [11093.441075] c2 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file 'devices'
    [11093.441111] c2 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '001'
    [11093.441368] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    [11093.441408] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: ohci_s5p_init, ohci:d2309d08
    [11093.441483] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: created debug files
    [11093.441519] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: irq 134, io mem 0x12590000
    [11093.441543] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: ohci_s5p_start, ohci:d2309d08
    [11093.499016] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: OHCI controller state
    [11093.499042] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: OHCI 1.0, NO legacy support registers
    [11093.499073] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: control 0x083 HCFS=operational CBSR=3
    [11093.499102] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: cmdstatus 0x00000 SOC=0
    [11093.499127] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: intrstatus 0x00000004 SF
    [11093.499153] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: intrenable 0x8000005a MIE RHSC UE RD WDH
    [11093.499184] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: hcca frame #0005
    [11093.499207] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.a 02000203 POTPGT=2 NPS NDP=3(3)
    [11093.499236] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.b 00000000 PPCM=0000 DR=0000
    [11093.499264] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.status 00008000 DRWE
    [11093.499291] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [0] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11093.499320] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [1] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11093.499350] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: roothub.portstatus [2] 0x00000100 PPS
    [11093.499402] c2 usb usb1: default language 0x0409
    [11093.499432] c2 usb usb1: udev 1, busnum 1, minor = 0
    [11093.499455] c2 usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [11093.499485] c2 usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [11093.499516] c2 usb usb1: Product: s5p OHCI
    [11093.499534] c2 usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.0.31-1665483 ohci_hcd
    [11093.499561] c2 usb usb1: SerialNumber: s5p-ohci
    [11093.499581] c2 call_battery_notify : VID : 0x1d6b, PID : 0x1 skipped.
    [11093.500914] c2 usb usb1: usb_probe_device
    [11093.500946] c2 usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
    [11093.500998] c2 usb usb1: adding 1-0:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
    [11093.501809] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: usb_probe_interface
    [11093.501832] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
    [11093.501857] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
    [11093.501888] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
    [11093.501907] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: standalone hub
    [11093.501925] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: no power switching (usb 1.0)
    [11093.501948] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: global over-current protection
    [11093.501971] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: power on to power good time: 4ms
    [11093.502001] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: local power source is good
    [11093.502023] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: no over-current condition exists
    [11093.502049] c2 hub 1-0:1.0: trying to enable port power on non-switchable hub
    [11093.502442] c2 drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '001'
    [11093.505713] c0 max77686: id=27, org=39, val=32
    [11093.600081] c3 hub 1-0:1.0: state 7 ports 3 chg 0000 evt 0000
    [11093.681937] c0 !@Sync 369
    [11094.500032] c2 s5p-ohci s5p-ohci: auto-stop root hub
    [11095.700047] c1 mdm_subsys_powerup: mdm modem restart timed out.
    [11095.700081] c1 Kernel panic - not syncing: subsystem_restart_wq_func[d65b7b40]: Failed to powerup external_modem!
    [11095.700123] c1 Backtrace: 
    [11095.700153] c1 [] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
    [11095.700190] c1  r7:ea666840 r6:c0ae38a4 r5:c0aeb090 r4:c0b99a80
    [11095.700225] c1 [] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [] (panic+0x7c/0x1b0)
    [11095.700267] c1 [] (panic+0x0/0x1b0) from [] (subsystem_restart_wq_func+0x214/0x250)
    [11095.700305] c1  r3:c0933d30 r2:d65b7b40 r1:c065d780 r0:c0934630
    [11095.700345] c1 [] (subsystem_restart_wq_func+0x0/0x250) from [] (process_one_work+0x144/0x498)
    [11095.700393] c1 [] (process_one_work+0x0/0x498) from [] (worker_thread+0x184/0x3e0)
    [11095.700437] c1 [] (worker_thread+0x0/0x3e0) from [] (kthread+0x90/0x98)
    [11095.700477] c1 [] (kthread+0x0/0x98) from [] (do_exit+0x0/0x768)
    [11095.700510] c1  r7:00000013 r6:c008f204 r5:c00ab764 r4:dbd6feb0
    [11095.700575] c0 CPU0: stopping
    [11095.700590] c0 Backtrace: 
    [11095.700613] c0 [] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
    [11095.700649] c0  r7:00000004 r6:00000006 r5:c09f4000 r4:00000000
    [11095.700688] c0 [] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [] (do_IPI+0x244/0x29c)
    [11095.700727] c0 [] (do_IPI+0x0/0x29c) from [] (__irq_svc+0x80/0x15c)
    [11095.700762] c0 Exception stack(0xc09f5ee0 to 0xc09f5f28)
    [11095.700789] c0 5ee0: 211dcb1b 00000000 547c7a53 000197b4 c0b970a4 00000000 c31720a8 c0aceafc
    [11095.700827] c0 5f00: c31720b8 c0c736f0 00000000 c09f5f54 547c7a53 c09f5f28 c00b6dd8 c005ae34
    [11095.700863] c0 5f20: 800f0013 ffffffff
    [11095.700890] c0 [] (exynos4_enter_idle+0x0/0x170) from [] (cpuidle_idle_call+0xd8/0x30c)
    [11095.700930] c0  r7:c0aceafc r6:c31720a8 r5:c09f4000 r4:c31720a8
    [11095.700966] c0 [] (cpuidle_idle_call+0x0/0x30c) from [] (cpu_idle+0xc4/0x104)
    [11095.701011] c0 [] (cpu_idle+0x0/0x104) from [] (rest_init+0xa0/0xa4)
    [11095.701045] c0  r7:00000000 r6:c003b264 r5:00000000 r4:c09f4000
    [11095.701081] c0 [] (rest_init+0x0/0xa4) from [] (start_kernel+0x2b4/0x308)
    [11095.701117] c0  r5:00000000 r4:c0ac6e88
    [11095.701141] c0 [] (start_kernel+0x0/0x308) from [] (0x40008040)
    [11095.701175] c2 CPU2: stopping
    [11095.701191] c2 Backtrace: 
    [11095.701215] c2 [] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
    [11095.701252] c2  r7:00000004 r6:00000006 r5:eb476000 r4:00000002
    [11095.701289] c2 [] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [] (do_IPI+0x244/0x29c)
    [11095.701328] c2 [] (do_IPI+0x0/0x29c) from [] (__irq_svc+0x80/0x15c)
    [11095.701362] c2 Exception stack(0xeb477f10 to 0xeb477f58)
    [11095.701387] c2 7f00:                                     815f545e 00000000 547c7a53 000197b4
    [11095.701426] c2 7f20: c0b970a4 00000000 c31820a8 c0aceafc c31820b8 c0c736f0 00000002 eb477f84
    [11095.701464] c2 7f40: 547c7a53 eb477f58 c00b6dd8 c005ae34 800f0013 ffffffff
    [11095.701500] c2 [] (exynos4_enter_idle+0x0/0x170) from [] (cpuidle_idle_call+0xd8/0x30c)
    [11095.701540] c2  r7:c0aceafc r6:c31820a8 r5:eb476000 r4:c31820a8
    [11095.701576] c2 [] (cpuidle_idle_call+0x0/0x30c) from [] (cpu_idle+0xc4/0x104)
    [11095.701617] c2 [] (cpu_idle+0x0/0x104) from [] (secondary_start_kernel+0x128/0x144)
    [11095.701656] c2  r7:c0b96b14 r6:10c0387d r5:00000002 r4:c0af0c84
    [11095.701690] c2 [] (secondary_start_kernel+0x0/0x144) from [] (0x40652bd4)
    [11095.701726] c2  r5:00000015 r4:65be806a
    [11095.701747] c3 CPU3: stopping
    [11095.701763] c3 Backtrace: 
    [11095.701788] c3 [] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
    [11095.701824] c3  r7:00000004 r6:00000006 r5:eb49e000 r4:00000003
    [11095.701862] c3 [] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [] (do_IPI+0x244/0x29c)
    [11095.701900] c3 [] (do_IPI+0x0/0x29c) from [] (__irq_svc+0x80/0x15c)
    [11095.701934] c3 Exception stack(0xeb49ff10 to 0xeb49ff58)
    [11095.701960] c3 ff00:                                     d13e8fce 00000000 547c7a53 000197b4
    [11095.701999] c3 ff20: c0b970a4 00000000 c318a0a8 c0aceafc c318a0b8 c0c736f0 00000003 eb49ff84
    [11095.702036] c3 ff40: 547c7a53 eb49ff58 c00b6dd8 c005ae34 800f0013 ffffffff
    [11095.702073] c3 [] (exynos4_enter_idle+0x0/0x170) from [] (cpuidle_idle_call+0xd8/0x30c)
    [11095.702113] c3  r7:c0aceafc r6:c318a0a8 r5:eb49e000 r4:c318a0a8
    [11095.702149] c3 [] (cpuidle_idle_call+0x0/0x30c) from [] (cpu_idle+0xc4/0x104)
    [11095.702191] c3 [] (cpu_idle+0x0/0x104) from [] (secondary_start_kernel+0x128/0x144)
    [11095.702229] c3  r7:c0b96b14 r6:10c0387d r5:00000003 r4:c0af0c84
    [11095.702264] c3 [] (secondary_start_kernel+0x0/0x144) from [] (0x40652bd4)
    [11095.702300] c3  r5:00000015 r4:57fcc06a
    [11095.802071] c1 notifier_call_chain : NOTIFY BAD sec_debug_panic_handler
    [11095.802102] c1 Rebooting in 1 seconds..
    [11096.799086] c1 sec_reboot (104, emergency)
```

After that, the bootloader starts.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/VHkakBCF) is the complete last_kmsg log.

How can I get a memory dump (that is needed as far as I understood from reading about desktop linux kernel debugging) to analyze the exact cause of the panic with `crash` or `bt` on my Android device or is their another way to resolve the backtrace?
Or should I even do something different to find out if this is a hardware problem or what software part is wrong telling from the current log alone?

Any help is much appreciated!

fightcookie